# Android Espresso Drag And Drop error Injecting events

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have been dealing with this problem for a whole day. The problem is that I am getting the following error when I try to drag something in my Instrumental Espresso tests.

```
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

This happens when I call this method

```
 onView(withId(R.id.any_id)).perform(CustomViewActions.touchAndDrag(200, 200));
```

Custom method

```
 public static ViewAction touchAndDrag(final float x, final float y, final long delay) {
        return new ViewAction() {

            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, final View view) {
                // Get view absolute position
                sendLinearSwipe(uiController,coordinatesClickOn,coordinatesMoveTo,precision,2000);

        };

    }
```

And `swipeLinaer` was taken from the sources of Espresso

```
  private static Swiper.Status sendLinearSwipe(UiController uiController, float[] startCoordinates,
                                                 float[] endCoordinates, float[] precision, int duration) {
        checkNotNull(uiController);
        checkNotNull(startCoordinates);
        checkNotNull(endCoordinates);
        checkNotNull(precision);

        float[][] steps = interpolate(startCoordinates, endCoordinates, SWIPE_EVENT_COUNT);
        final int delayBetweenMovements = duration / steps.length;

        MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvents.sendDown(uiController, startCoordinates, precision).down;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
                if (!MotionEvents.sendMovement(uiController, downEvent, steps[i])) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Injection of move event as part of the swipe failed. Sending cancel event.");
                    MotionEvents.sendCancel(uiController, downEvent);
                    return Swiper.Status.FAILURE;
                }

                long desiredTime = downEvent.getDownTime() + delayBetweenMovements * i;
                long timeUntilDesired = desiredTime - SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                if (timeUntilDesired > 10) {
                    uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(timeUntilDesired);
                }
            }

            if (!MotionEvents.sendUp(uiController, downEvent, endCoordinates)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Injection of up event as part of the swipe failed. Sending cancel event.");
                MotionEvents.sendCancel(uiController, downEvent);
                return Swiper.Status.FAILURE;
            }
        } finally {
            downEvent.recycle();
        }
        return Swiper.Status.SUCCESS;
    }
```

The problem is that this doesn't work **ONLY IF TOUCH** listener is set

Like that

```
    anyView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

So it really doesn't matter what kind of listener is set, but the fact it is set causes the error.

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 2):

The way Android manage swiping object is not so clear.
When you try to drag something, Android generate a picture of that thing that follows your finger and gives you the idea of dragging. 
The problem is that the component of the system that generate that effect is not coming from your application but from another app and so Android believe that during the dragging you are touching another "app".
The same problem appear when accidentally you touch the system keyboard.

The solution is sign your apk with system certificate and add INJECT_EVENTS permission on your manifest.